# Nav2 Unable to Switch BT (Galactic)

Tags: ros2, nav2

This question is asked a few times and I tried changing the yaml file but still when I load groot live monitoring, its always default bt loaded. Can you anyone suggest suggestions/corrections to try. Unless when I use Simple Commander API for Navigatopose and passing BT will change it, if this is some sort of bug or something ?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead ... https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Groot live monitoring was removed from Nav2 long ago for many reasons, but among them was the fact that it used ZMQ which caused issues switching BTs inside of groot. I'm having a hard time precisely understanding the issue you're having and where that lies, but that seems like related information worth mentioning.

Galactic has been EOL for almost 18 months, you really should upgrade to Humble or newer. I'm sure there are several bugs and new features which you don't have being on such an old distribution. We stopped supporting that with active updates approximately 2 years ago.

Comment: Is there any way to know which BT is loaded ? Like Rviz shows which BT it is using for NavigatetoPose ? I just wanna make sure that the right BT is getting loaded.

Comment: Checking the logs, we log any changes in BTs